# Customizing matplotlib image display to add copy/paste

Tags: python, excel, copy, matplotlib, paste

I would like to customize matplotlib image display so that i can type control-c and it will copy the image to the clipboard so then i can copy it to openoffice spreadsheet to organize all of my raw data and image results. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but if Matplotlib doesn't already have the copy functionality built in, I think it'd take a fair amount of work to add it. If you are in need of a quicker solution, you could also consider exporting the image from Matplotlib to a file (which can be done from the Python code) and then importing it into OpenOffice.

Comment: If you don't mind manual quick hack solutions, I'd suggest the Windows Snipping Tool (Comes with Windows 7). It gives a very quick way to select area of screen and copy it right away.

Comment: im on ubuntu! I think i have found solutions to actually saving the image and then copying it in linux, i was truly wondering if i could modify the interactive matplotlib graph displayer so that it could capture control-c and then   call the copy function i create.

Comment: **Open issue [#1987 Add "copy to clipboard" to the Toolbar](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1987)** since 2013, awaiting people to contribute code for each of the backends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the wx backend, `FigureCanvasWxAgg` has  a `Copy_to_Clipboard` method you can use.  You could bind the CTRL+C key event to call this method.  For an example, see this [sample code](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/user_interfaces/printing_in_wx.html).

Comment: but is there any way to have the graph automatically update when you call graph functions like plot(), title() (interactive mode like in ipython?)

Comment: you can clear the figure and redraw, or you can use something like the methods for animation on this page: http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations

Comment: arg, wx backend doesn't work for me, plots once doesn't work.  stuck with tk backend

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't look like the Tk canvas has similar support for the clipboard: http://matplotlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/matplotlib/trunk/matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py?revision=8657&view=markup

Comment: oh, did you mean the update/animation?  try googling "matplotlib tk animation", it seems to bring up a number of references that might help.

Comment: The below i posted is what i wanted, but i still have no clue how to, in general, copy an image to a clipboard so i can paste into openoffice

Answer (score 2):

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
if not globals().has_key('__figure'):
    __figure = matplotlib.pyplot.figure

def on_key(event):
    print event
    if event.key=='c':
        #print event.canvas.__dict__#.Copy_to_Clipboard(event=event)
       # print event.canvas._tkphoto.__dict__
        plt.savefig("/tmp/fig.png")
def my_figure():
    fig = __figure()
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event',on_key)
    return fig    
matplotlib.pyplot.figure = my_figure
```

This works for tk backend, but i have no clue how to copy an image to a clipboard. For text, i can use xclip, but images dont work! And for some reason the wx backend doesnt work too well on ubuntu...